# How can I print the owner's email using group by in opportunity?

Tags: apex, soql

```
    public class Temp {
    public static void b(){
        AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [Select owner.email from Opportunity where LastModifiedDate <  LAST_N_DAYS:10 group by owner.email];

        for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
            System.debug('owner email' + ar.get('owner.email'));
        }
    }
}
```

Here `ar.get('owner.email')` this is not working giving an error like this
[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alias for the field in the aggregate soql as shown below:

```
Select owner.email eml from Opportunity where LastModifiedDate <  LAST_N_DAYS:10 group by owner.email
```

and use the alias in aggregate result get statement

```
ar.get('eml')
```

Comment: but alias only work on aggregate functions

Comment: Yes, field aliasing work only on aggregate SOQL. In your case this should solve the error.